# Create Folder based on ID when registering

Tags: php

I have my register form and when some one registers I want to create a file with the name of there user id, then I want to right a index.php with code that will redirect to the main site.

the location I need the folder to create is example.com/uploads this will be for there images and stuff..

the issue I am having is it refuses to create the folder.

```
    function create_user($email, $full_name, $job_title, $password){

        if (email_exists($email)) {
            return false;
        } else {        

                $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                $db = dbconnect();
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users(Email, FullName, JobTitle, Bio, Password, ValidationCode, Active) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
                $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $email, $full_name, $job_title, $bio, $hashed_password, $validation_code, $active);
                $stmt->execute();
                $last_row = $stmt->insert_id;
                $stmt->close(); 



           $MainFolder ="uploads";
        $dir = $stmt->insert_id;            


        $file_to_write = 'index.php';           

        if( is_dir($dir) === false ){
            mkdir($dir);
        }
        $file = fopen($MainFolder.'/'. $dir . '/' . $file_to_write,"w");

        // write content into
        fwrite($file,"<?php header('location: http://example.com');");                                    

                return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Is the `uploads` folder writable by your webserver?

Comment: $last_row is not defined, you should try retrieving the last ID. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php for more information.

Comment: yes it is so basically I want example.com/uploads/ user id but I am not sure I'm get the last_row right

Comment: Like I said just putting in $last_row isn't going to work, you need to put the actual MYSQL mysql_insert_id into the value, with the PDO library you're using this can be done with the link I provided earlier.

Comment: I am not using PDO I am using mysqli prepared stmts

Comment: My Bad, take a look at the same function but then made for mysqli, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: I already added that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143049/discussion-between-peter-m-and-case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your current code:

```
$dir = $last_row;
```

Into:

```
$dir = $stmt->insert_id;
```

Then echo that value to make sure you're getting results.
Also enable error_reporting or check your error log to see any errors.